# Making form data stay on PHP page from a multi select form

Tags: php, html, forms

Okay so I have 1 html page setup with a [HTML multiple Attribute from](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple). This is how it is setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "otherpage.php" method= "post"> 
    <select name = "cars[]" multiple="multiple" size="4"> 
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
    <button type = "submit" value= "Submit">Submit</button> 
    <button type = "reset" value= "Clear">Clear</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a second php page, lets call it "otherpage.php" and this is how it is setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <form action = "" method= "post">
   Name:  <input type = "text" name = "yourname" />
   <button type = "submit" value= "Submit2">Submit</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="f" value=<?php $cars= array(); $cars= $_POST['cars']; print_r($cars); ?> />
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['f'])) {echo ($_POST['f']);}
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the first submit on the first html page the array prints out fine. Then when I hit the other submit again on "otherpage.php", the array no longer exists and I get an error. How can I get the cars array to stay forever no matter how many times I submit on otherpage.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store the data in a session variable.

You have to have session_start() at the top of every file you want to use it on.

Then when you get the $_POST values:

```
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

After that, you can do what you want with it on any other file.

Comment: So basically add session_start() in a php block on the top of both pages right? Then on otherpage.php I would do something like $_SESSION['cars'] = $_POST; ?

Comment: Yes. You could either cast the entire post array in to a single session variable and then access elements from the array or do a session variable for each element in the post array. It's  up to you.

Comment: Also, make sure that session_start() gets put in your file before there is ANY output at all or it will fail. I always use it right under the <?php tag just as a course of habit.

Comment: So lets say I cast the entire post array into a single session variable by doing  $_SESSION['cars'] = $_POST; Would I print it by doing something like print_r($_POST)

Comment: A couple of things. First, your <select> tag needs name="cars" or it won't submit at all.

Then, if you only want the selection of cars, then you do $_SESSION['cars'] = $_POST['cars'];

Comment: Okay great! I am also assuming that print_r('cars') wont work so I probably have to do something like print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: correct. Or print_r($_SESSION['cars'] or it will print out everything. But just like any other array, if $_SESSION['cars'] holds an array of values, you can iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implode the array to string and explode it again to get back your array or encode it to a json string and reencode it again either way will work

```
<?php 
$cars = isset($_POST['cars']) ?
$_POST['cars'] : isset($_POST['f']) ? explode(',',$_POST['f']) : [];
?>
DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <form action = "" method= "post">
   Name:  <input type = "text" name = "yourname" />
   <button type = "submit" value= "Submit2">Submit</button>
   <input type="hidden" name="f" value="<?php echo implode(',', $cars)?>"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer, but it would be petty to give up my tests without showing you my version too.

The `echo '<pre>'...` is just for displaying results. Notice the use of `value="<?php echo print_r($cars, true); ?>"`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cars'])) {
    $cars = $_POST['cars'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['f'])) {
    $cars = $_POST['f'];
} else {
    $cars = array();
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($cars, true) . '</pre>';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Name:  <input type="text" name="yourname" />
            <?php
            foreach ($cars as $car) {
                echo '<br/>' . $car . '<input type="radio" name="car" value="' . $car . '" />';
            }
            ?>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit2">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="f" value="<?php echo print_r($cars, true); ?>" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck.

---

### EDIT 2: Using session

You don't need a hidden input anymore. I changed page names and a bit of html also.

#### Page cars_select.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cars selecting page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="cars_list.php" method= "post"> 
            <select name = "cars[]" multiple="multiple" size="4"> 
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select> 
            <button type="submit" id="selectSubmit" name="selectSubmit" value="Submit">
                Cars selected. List them!
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Page cars_list.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// Upon clicking on "selectSubmit" button.
if (isset($_POST['selectSubmit'])) {
    // Set POST received cars list as session variable.
    $_SESSION['cars'] = isset($_POST['cars']) ? $_POST['cars'] : array();

    echo 'Called by CARS SELECT page.';
}

// Upon clicking on "listSubmit" button.
if (isset($_POST['listSubmit'])) {
    echo 'Called by CARS LIST page.';
}

// Test display of SESSION array.
echo '<br/><br/>Session is: <pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>';

// Read cars list from session.
$cars = $_SESSION['cars'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cars listing page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hr/>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Name:  <input type="text" name="yourname" />
            <?php
            foreach ($cars as $car) {
                echo '<br/>' . $car . '<input type="radio" name="car" value="' . $car . '" />';
            }
            ?>
            <button type="submit" id="listSubmit" name="listSubmit" value="Submit">Refresh page!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is always good to see multiple solutions.

Comment: You are very welcome. But, indeed, the use of the session object is the (only) recommended one.

Comment: So I tried all the solutions on this page and it turns out yours is the only one that worked in my case. I noticed that this works because of php echo print_r($cars, true) but what if I did not want to use print_r to print out the array. Instead I wanted to format the output using foreach loop and an echo inside the loop. Would I need to change the hidden input tag on the form?

Comment: @funnystone64 I'm glad that works. I don't really understand your task: "_to format the output using foreach loop and an echo inside the loop._". Which output? The value of the hidden input?

Comment: Something like this '$cars= $_POST['cars'];
                                    foreach ($cars as $thevalue) { 
                                    echo "<br/>$thevalue" ,'<input type = "radio" name = "car" value = "$thevalue" />';          
                                }'

Comment: Weel, if I understand correctly, you want to build a part of your html output using the $cars array, but with the condition that the $cars array should be preserved at any time as the value in the hidden input. Right? If it's correct, than nothing stopps you to use $cars array as you wish, where you wish it, as long as you don't change it's items at all and you keep it inside hidden input as before (untouched value attribute). If you need, you can even make copies of it, in which you can change the items too. I reedited my answer to mirror how I would do it.

Comment: You are correct and this is where I have hit a wall. Your code is correct and it also what I would do and it works perfectly for the first submit. But for whatever reason when I hit submit a second time I get "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" almost like the cars array no longer exists..... How is that possible when I am sending the data back to the same page. print_r works totally fine no matter how many times I hit submit. When outputting using a foreach loop it will not work for some reason.

Comment: Question: we are talking about only one php page, right? So, when you click `Submit2` button for the first time, it works great. And when you click `Submit2` button for the second time it doesn't work anymore. Right?

Comment: Or are you still receiving the array from the index.php in a first step?

Comment: 2 pages, 1st is a page that looks exactly like the first block of code in my original post. The 2nd page now looks exactly like your answer. When hitting submit on the 1st page, all the form data transfers and outputs in the foreach loop with no issues. When hitting submit2 on the second page, that is where it all falls apart. The values do not hold. I read that session variables are how to keep the form data but I tried the first answer on this page and it too had all the form data disappear after submit2. I really appreciate the help you have given so far.

Comment: Ok, let me test it 5 mins

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Because the array in hidden is saved as string. And you can't loop through it. Interesting thing. I make further.

Comment: Well I teseted, I searched, I found, I don't liked it. So, my advice is: ensure that the version with session works, because what you tried here keeps beeing problematic. The session is the correct way. So I will help you to resolve the session solution until it works. Ok?

Comment: Yeah that fine, honestly dont worry too much I guess I will figure it out one way or another. I will be leaving my computer for about 3 hours and I really appreciate the responses.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day and feel free to ask anything. Bye.

Comment: Hey I just had a chance to test the new solution you gave and IT WORKED!!!! You made my day :D

Comment: With pleasure. It's nice when things works smooth. You should upvote or reaccept @Difster's answer, because he was the first with the working idea. I'll certainly upvote him ;-) Good luck in the future.